# Rails 3 plugin css

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to have public directory in my plugin?
I want to use css and javascript from my plugin folder, not from /app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do this yet, but if you watch the latest DHH talk from RailsConf, it looks like he wants it for Rails 3.1.  Looks like it will work just like views currently work, which makes sense to me.

Otherwise, you should probably setup a route that points your filename to a controller (perhaps something like AssetsController?) and serve a view as a CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

The css pages are in public/stylesheets and the javascript in public/javascript not in app/

Comment: Yes, sorry..
but I want vendor/plugins/myplugin/public/stylesheets and vendor/plugins/myplugin/public/javascript